# How to access JS file from within template html page? Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

I know this is a duplicate, but I cannot figure this out.
I have a file structure like:
[image]

How can I link factoid-page.js into factoid-page.html ?

I have tried:  `<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/factoid-page.js}"></script>`

This does not work.

Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accroading to this page: [Add CSS and JS to Thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-css-js#1-directory-structure)

> For CSS and JavaScript files, the default directory is src/main/resources/static..

Please reorganize your `static` folder:

1. put `.js` files into src/main/resources/static/js/
2. put `.css` files into src/main/resources/static/css/

and try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/factoid-page.js}"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized my JS is being loaded, but my bootstrap modal are not working